# Are $W_1$ and $W_2$ same? How they are different?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let 
\begin{align}
W_1&=\{(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)\in \mathbb C^n \mid a_1=\mu a_n, \text{for some fixed $\mu \in \mathbb C$} \}\\
W_2&=\{(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)\in \mathbb C^n \mid \frac{a_1}{a_2}=\mu , \text{for some fixed $\mu \in \mathbb C$}\}. 
\end{align}
What is the difference between two subsets?

I know that $W_1$ is a subspace with dimension $n-1$. Since $W_1=\{(\mu a_n,a_2,...,a_n):$for some fixed $\mu \in \mathbb C\}=span\{(\mu,0,0,..,1),e_2,e_3,...,e_{n-1}\}$

What is the problem with $W_2$?
 Are $W_1$ and $W_2$ same? How they are different?In the answer key, It is given that $W_2$ is not a vector space. Answer given as $(0,0,...,0)\notin W_2$. Why? For $(0,0,...,0)$ vector, $a_1=0,a_n=0 \implies a_1=\mu a_n=0=\mu 0$. Satisfying the condition. right?

Comment: I've reformatted to make the definitions of $W_1$ and $W_2$ line up. Unfortunately, they're identical, so it's tough to see what you're asking. Is there a typo perhaps?

Comment: I have edited my typo. Sorry for the typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a_1/a_2 = \mu$, then $a_2$ cannot be zero. Hence the zero-vector is not in $W_2$.

This is more or less a trick question, alas.

Comment: But Can't we write $a_1=\mu a_2$?

Comment: Okay. $a_1/a_2$ means $a_1.a_2^{-1}=\mu$. $0$ has no inverse. so $a_2 a_2^{-1}$ need not exist. Am I giving correct explanation?

Comment: Well...I'd simply say "Suppose that $(0, 0, \ldots) \in W_2$. Then $0/0 = \mu$, which is impossible."

Answer (score 1):

$$
W_1=\{(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)\in \mathbb C^n \mid a_1=\mu a_n, \text{for some fixed $\mu \in \mathbb C$} \}\\ $$

is not  the same as $$W_2=\{(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)\in \mathbb C^n \mid \frac{a_1}{a_2}=\mu , \text{for some fixed $\mu \in \mathbb C$}\}. 
$$

Note that for $(0,0,...,0)$ while $a_1 =\mu a_2$ for every $\mu$, we do not have $$\frac {a_1}{a_2} = \mu$$ because the expression  $\frac {0}{0}$ is undefined.